# How to communicate between a shell and its subshell process? (call by execution not sourcing)

Tags: shell

I have a main shell file `A.sh`, it calls `B.sh` by executing it. I want to know how I can return a variable from `B.sh` to `A.sh`?

For example

```
#B.sh
a=123

#A.sh
./B.sh

echo $a
```

I am expecting the result `123` on the terminal. I know the above doesn't work, please show me how to achieve what I want. Thanks.

Comment: It didn't because I am calling by execution not sourcing. If I use . ./B.sh then it would work. But I am bounded to use execution.

Comment: so why are you "bounded to use execution"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`B.sh` cannot affect the environment of `A.sh`. There are two options.

1. Have `B.sh` write to standard output, then capture its output.

   ```
   a=$( ./B.sh )
   ```

   `$(...)` is part of the POSIX standard, but if for some reason you are using a shell that does not support this syntax, the older form

   ```
   a=`./B.sh`
   ```

   may work.
2. Have `B.sh` write to a file, and have `A.sh` read from the file after `B.sh` exits.